# BeagleBone Black default Poky image not booting when copying files

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack

I am using Yocto Kirkstone. I want to build and run the exemplary core-image-minimal for BBB. After the build, when I `dd` the SD card with this command:

```
sudo dd if=core-image-minimal-beaglebone-yocto.wic of=/dev/<media>
```

Everything works- I can boot from the SD card. The `boot` partition then includes of the following files/ directories:

```
am335x-boneblack.dtb  am335x-bone.dtb  am335x-bonegreen.dtb  extlinux  MLO  u-boot.img  zImag
```

Following different tutorials on how to copy the built files manually, there is no mention of the `extlinux` directory and `am335x-bone.dtb  am335x-bonegreen.dtb` files (I think these blobs are for BB white and BB green, so not needed). But the thing is, my image wont boot (probably) because of the lack of the `extlinux` dir and the `extlinux.conf` file inside (its a guess). Why does it boot without that dir in the tutorials (i.e., [here](https://tutorialadda.com/yocto/create-linux-image-for-beaglebone-black-using-yocto-build-system))?